# Django - How to exclude already selected object from queryset in form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am seeking an advice on how to approach the following problem:

I am having these models: **Event** > **EventAttendees** > **EventRoster**.
Every event has attendees (users) which I would like to assign to specific positions (attributes of EventRoster) for that particular Event.

*Example: -Event(Football/Soccer game), attendees: (Bob, John, Mike, Steve), EventRoster: (Bob = goaltender, John = left wing, Mike = center, Steve = defence)*

Idea is to have a form for event, where anyone from attendees can be assigned to any of the positions. Each form field would represent a position, where attendee can be selected, **if that attendee was not already selected for different position**.

My problem is, that I am selecting attendees from EventAttendees.objects.all() or .filter(event__pk=pk) without updating this queryset to exclude attendees that are already selected for some other position.

What I am aiming for is to exclude attendee from queryset if that attendee is already selected in form field (position). Basically to have empty queryset once all attendees are assigned to all positions.

What would be the best way to approach this? I have found similarities in so called chained fields, but I guess these are not applicable in this scenario. Probably I will not be able to this without ajax as field values on form will not change unless form is submitted.

Thank you in advance for your support!

```
class Event(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
        attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='EventAttendees')

class EventAttendees(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_event')
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='ice')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user','event')

class EventRoster(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event_roster')
    goalie = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    center = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    left_wing = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    defensemen = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

class RosterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    goalie = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EventAttendees.objects.none())
    center = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EventAttendees.objects.none())
    left_wing = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EventAttendees.objects.none())
    defensemen = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=EventAttendees.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['goalie'].queryset = EventAttendees.objects.filter(event__pk=50).distinct()
        self.fields['center'].queryset = EventAttendees.objects.filter(event__pk=50).distinct()
        self.fields['left_wing'].queryset = EventAttendees.objects.filter(event__pk=50).distinct()
        self.fields['defensemen'].queryset = EventAttendees.objects.filter(event__pk=50).distinct()

    class Meta:
        model = EventRoster
        fields = ['goalie','center','left_wing','defensemen']
```

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate data in your form without a page-load? You will need to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: In the Django model write a clean method for fields that depend on each other. This prevents submitting invalid data. Also write some javascript to simplify the ui. Your positions are choice fields, but you do not have to present them like option selects. Just drag and drop each attendee on a position?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really undestand the logic except i see the whole code i.e views and forms but i think the `exclude()` function would come in handy when querying the model